# Connectivity change in android 7

Tags: android

I m developing an application for targeting `android 7` and i m have to do  something on `connectivity change`. How i can  do this.

Can any one help me with sample code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please explain your problem in brief

Comment: @YoLo How i use Job Scheduler

Answer (score 1):

As of Android 7 (Nougat) receivers that are registered with the manifest will no longer be called.

You need to register it with

```
Context.registerReceiver()
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges) here

That means that you will need to register for those in your Actviity/Fragment where you need them.